# jQuery resize image (keep aspect ratio) before upload it

Tags: jquery, image, resize

I got this code to check if the file is even an image and if so upload it:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$(".choosebutton").change(function(e) {
    $(".choosebutton").hide();
    $("#loadgif").show();
    var image, file;
        file = this.files[0];
        image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
            var width = this.width;
            var height = this.height;
            if(height > 100)
            {
                $('.standardbutton').trigger('click');  // submit button
            }
            else
            {
                alert('this is not an image -_-');
                $(".choosebutton").show();
                $("#loadgif").hide();
                return false;
            }
        };
        image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
```

I need to resize the image when the height or width is bigger than 700px.
Ofc I allready searched for a solution but it's either cropping and resizing allready inside div loaded image and so on..

**EDIT:**

Here is also the form:

```
<form action="doupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="datei" class="choosebutton" accept="image/*">
        <button type="submit" class="standardbutton" style="display: none;">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `if ((file = this.files[0]))` This is not valid Javascript. An if statement expects a test condition not an assignment of a variable. You code does not make a lot of sense either. I also don't see any upload script.

Comment: Why do you need the server side code? I need client side resizing. I will add the form above now just in case. And I do upload Images with that oO

Comment: Well if it is all nonsense and it works, why are you asking? Oh and yes technically you can do an assignment in an `if` statement but it is very bad practice and if you are doing it you really should know what you are doing.

Comment: I can upload the images but I need to resize them client side when they are too big. Just like I allready explained

Comment: I did not say you had to remove the if statement cause it  clearly serves a function. It was just not the best code I have seen and confusing too. Plus assigning a variable value in an if statement is a no go. Just to say I am not just making something up.